# Background palettes for tableView cells

Tags: swift

I was trying to customize cells with adding bg colors. I have figured out how to make them with specific color. But my goal is to use a pallete of colors. So I made array with 3 colors in it:

```
var bgPalette = ["red: 105/255.0, green:210/255.0, blue:231/255.0", "red: 167/255.0, green:219/255.0, blue:216/255.0", "red: 224/255.0, green:228/255.0, blue:204/255.0"]
```

and trying to use those palletes in cell

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(bgPalette[index], alpha:1.0 )
```

But it does not work.

So Viney from Udemy's "The Complete iOS8 and Swift Course" told me to create 4 variables for each color like so:

```
let myColor1: UIColor = UIColor( red: CGFloat(110/255.0), green: CGFloat(110/255.0), blue: CGFloat(255/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0) )
let myColor2: UIColor = UIColor( red: CGFloat(0/255.0), green: CGFloat(110/255.0), blue: CGFloat(11/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0) )
let myColor3: UIColor = UIColor( red: CGFloat(0/255.0), green: CGFloat(0/255.0), blue: CGFloat(255/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0) )
let myColor4: UIColor = UIColor( red: CGFloat(210/255.0), green: CGFloat(10/255.0), blue: CGFloat(255/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0) )
```

And to create array with those colors:

```
var paletteArray:[UIColor] = [myColor1,myColor2,myColor3,myColor4]
```

And after to take those colors from palette in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
cell.backgroundColor = paletteArray[indexPath.row]
```

But it did not helped. I bet I am somewhere around the right answer, but as soon as I am noob in Swift, I need your help.

Any ideas how to fix it without objective-c?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with 'it does not work'? Do you get an error?

Comment: Yes, Mr. Woerz. I get error: fatal error: Array index out of range
(lldb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fails to tell us what goes wrong, but I think I see two errors

```
cell.backgroundColor = paletteArray[indexPath.row]
```

Should be

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = paletteArray[indexPath.row % paletteArray.count]
```

---

`%` is the modulo operator, it returns the rest of a division. it is a precaution here for the case that your tableview has more than 4 rows.

```
0 % 4 -> 0
1 % 4 -> 1
2 % 4 -> 2
3 % 4 -> 3
4 % 4 -> 0
5 % 5 -> 1
```

As you see the index will always stay in the range of your array.

Comment: Thank you sir. May I ask what is the difference? I know what % stands for, but why do I have to use it? Could you please explain me my mistake?